# Python .pyd equivalent on linux

Tags: python, c++, linux, python-2.7

I have some c++ code that is working as a python module using boost.
It is actually a plugin of another c++ python module.

On windows, I have to link against a `libavg.pyd` file of this library.

On linux I tried linking against `libavg.so`, but when doing that, dlopen fails with undefined references to functions that should be defined in `libavg.pyd`.

What is the equivalent of linking to a .pyd file on linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On linux .pyd equivalent is .so files.

I'm not know about Boost::Python specifics, but you can try to use script like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

module = Extension('ModuleName', sources=['yourmodule.cpp'], language="c++")

setup(name="ModuleName",
      version='1.0',
      description='My package',
      ext_modules=[module])
```

And after this just import your built module with .so-extension.

Comment: Nevermind, for that library on windows it had just one .pyd, while on linux I had to link to about 10 .so files.